# Count how many times <li> is printed

Tags: php, css

I need to check how many times li tag is printed

```
<li>
  <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
  </ul>
</li>
```

If tag is printed 4 times, I need to start a new row. I am printing these values inside a `foreach` loop to retreive wp menu. I get all correct the only error is that it prints all values in one row by adding menus in columns.

I need to set if row is printed with for values to start new row.

It should look like this

```
AUDI        BMW        MERCEDES        TOYOTA
HONDA       FERARI     RENAULT         PASSAT
SKODA       FIAT
```

not like this (EVERYTHING IN ONE ROW)

```
AUDI        BMW        MERCEDES        TOYOTA HONDA       FERARI     RENAULT   ETC
```

Complete code

```
<ul class="rd-navbar-nav">
    <?php
    $count = 0;
    $submenu = false;
    foreach( $menuitems as $item ):
        $link = $item->url;
        $title = $item->title;
        // item does not have a parent so menu_item_parent equals 0 (false)
        if ( !$item->menu_item_parent ):
        // save this id for later comparison with sub-menu items
        $parent_id = $item->ID;
    ?>

    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title"> <?php echo $title; ?> </a>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( $parent_id == $item->menu_item_parent ): ?>

        <?php if ( !$submenu ): $submenu = true; ?>
        <ul class="rd-navbar-megamenu">
        <?php endif; ?>
            <li>
              <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
                <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a>
              </ul>
            </li>

           <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu ): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ): ?>
    </li>
    <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

    <?php $count++; endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Generated HTML

```
<ul class="rd-navbar-nav">

    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/" class="title"> Početna </a>
    </li>


    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/o-nama/" class="title"> O nama </a>
     </li>


    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/termoizolacioni-paneli/" class="title"> Termoizolacioni paneli </a>
        <ul class="rd-navbar-megamenu">
            <li>
                <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
                    <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/termoizolacioni-paneli/krovni-paneli-2/" class="title">Krovni paneli</a>
                 </ul>
            </li> 
            <li>
                <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
                    <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/termoizolacioni-paneli/krovni-paneli/" class="title">Zidni paneli</a>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
                    <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/termoizolacioni-paneli/frigo-paneli/" class="title">Frigo paneli</a>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>


    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/ostali-proizvodi/" class="title"> Ostali proizvodi </a>

        <ul class="rd-navbar-megamenu">
            <li>
                <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
                    <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/profilisani-limovi/" class="title">Profilisani limovi</a>
                </ul>
            </li>
             <li>
                <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
                    <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/profilisani-limovi/" class="title">Vijčana roba</a>
                </ul>
            </li>
             <li>
                <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
                    <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/profilisani-limovi/" class="title">Komunalna oprema</a>
                </ul>
            </li>
             <li>
                <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
                    <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/profilisani-limovi/" class="title">Profili za suhu gradnju</a>
                </ul>
            </li>
             <li>
                <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
                    <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/profilisani-limovi/" class="title">Ostali</a>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>   


    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Are you looping through an array? Please include all related code. Also - it would be better to show the HTML that you expect as output instead of text.

Comment: Post the PHP code (loop part), and how are you willing to create a new row, with `<br />`?

Comment: Just use bootstrap and their classes, everything will be fine

Comment: You could probably achieve this with CSS. Without seeing your expected markup - it's difficult to give an actual answer.

Comment: I have added code I am using

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with CSS, using these two rules (I take it your `li` elements are inline-blocks):

```
.rd-megamenu-list li {
  float: left;
}
.rd-megamenu-list li:nth-child(4n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

This will put every 4th `li` item in a new line.

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.rd-megamenu-list li {
  float: left;
}

.rd-megamenu-list li:nth-child(4n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
  <li>LISTITEM</li>
  <li>LISTITEM</li>
  <li>LISTITEM</li>
  <li>LISTITEM</li>
  <li>LISTITEM</li>
  <li>LISTITEM</li>
  <li>LISTITEM</li>
  <li>LISTITEM</li>
  <li>LISTITEM</li>
  <li>LISTITEM</li>
  <li>LISTITEM</li>
  <li>LISTITEM</li>
  <li>LISTITEM</li>
  <li>LISTITEM</li>
  <li>LISTITEM</li>
</ul>
```

Here's a similar set of CSS with the genereated HTML you added. I added `clear: left;` for all first-level `li` s  which I don't know if you want it since that wasn't part of your original question:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.rd-navbar-megamenu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

.rd-navbar-megamenu li {
  float: left;
}

.rd-navbar-megamenu li:nth-child(4n+1) {
  clear: left;
}

.rd-navbar-nav>li {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="rd-navbar-nav">

  <li>
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/" class="title"> Početna </a>
  </li>


  <li>
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/o-nama/" class="title"> O nama </a>
  </li>


  <li>
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/termoizolacioni-paneli/" class="title"> Termoizolacioni paneli </a>
    <ul class="rd-navbar-megamenu">
      <li>
        <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
          <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/termoizolacioni-paneli/krovni-paneli-2/" class="title">Krovni paneli</a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
          <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/termoizolacioni-paneli/krovni-paneli/" class="title">Zidni paneli</a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
          <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/termoizolacioni-paneli/frigo-paneli/" class="title">Frigo paneli</a>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>


  <li>
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/ostali-proizvodi/" class="title"> Ostali proizvodi </a>

    <ul class="rd-navbar-megamenu">
      <li>
        <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
          <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/profilisani-limovi/" class="title">Profilisani limovi</a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
          <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/profilisani-limovi/" class="title">Vijčana roba</a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
          <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/profilisani-limovi/" class="title">Komunalna oprema</a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
          <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/profilisani-limovi/" class="title">Profili za suhu gradnju</a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
          <a href="http://localhost:8080/company/profilisani-limovi/" class="title">Ostali</a>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>


  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I have tried, I added those css lines in my custom css but nothing happened. It does not work

Comment: I looked at the code in your quetsion again and I realized that your `li` tags are wrapped in `a` tags, so try to replace `li` with `a` in my code above

Comment: I have replaced your code with a, nothing happens .rd-megamenu-list a {
       float: left;
     }

     .rd-megamenu-list a:nth-child(4n+1) {
       clear: left;
     }

Comment: Can you add the gererated HTML code to your question, and possible also the CSS that appies to the elements used here?

Comment: I have added generated html

Comment: please note the addition to my answer

Comment: Still not able to get good result, i have checked your code is ok but it does not work on my side

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS to do the formatting.  this will wrap the items after 4 are displayed.  you may need to add text-align and display properties depending on the rest of your CSS>

CSS

```
.25p { width: 24.99%; }
```

HTML

```
<li class='25p'>
  <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I inserted condition at the end of the loop:

```
<ul class="rd-navbar-nav">
    <?php
    $count = 0;
    $submenu = false;
    foreach( $menuitems as $item ):
        $link = $item->url;
        $title = $item->title;
        // item does not have a parent so menu_item_parent equals 0 (false)
        if ( !$item->menu_item_parent ):
        // save this id for later comparison with sub-menu items
        $parent_id = $item->ID;
    ?>

    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title"> <?php echo $title; ?> </a>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( $parent_id == $item->menu_item_parent ): ?>

        <?php if ( !$submenu ): $submenu = true; ?>
        <ul class="rd-navbar-megamenu">
        <?php endif; ?>
            <li>
              <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
                <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a>
              </ul>
            </li>

           <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu ): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ): ?>
    </li>
    <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

    <?php 
$count++; 
if ($count % 4 == 0) {
     echo '<br>';
}
endforeach; 
?>

</ul>
```

Comment: I am trying to break child li not parent

Comment: Then instead `echo '<br>';` try to use `echo "</ul><ul>";`

Answer (score 0):

You can break it to chunks in php:

```
<?php foreach( $menuitems as $item ):
  if (++$i % 4 == 0) : ?>
     </ul><ul class="rd-navbar-nav">
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, using CSS is the right way to achieve your goal, but to answer your question here is the PHP code:

```
<ul>
<?php
// Array of items
$cars = array('AUDI', 'BMW', 'MERCEDES', 'YOTOTA', 'HONDA', 'FERARI', 'RENAULT', 'PASSAT', 'SKODA', 'FIAT');

// Start count at 0
$count = 0;
foreach($cars as $car){
// Add 1 to the count
$count++;
?>
    <li>
        <?=$car?>
    </li>
<?php
    // If this is the fourth element
    if($count === 4){
        // Print a line break
        echo "<br />";
        // And reset the count
        $count = 0;
    }
}
?>
</ul>
```

This will add a line break after every 4th element.